# How do I get a Production API Key?

Tags: sabre

I am new to Sabre and its products and I am not sure where to turn to for help. I need to get 2 things

1. A production API Key and
2. Access to soap API's

Currently, I am not sure how to do either. I have a sabre account with test credentials, but I need production credentials and access to soap API's in order to proceed with building my application. Who should I contact in order to escalate my account privileges?

Comment: This is a product question so not suitable here. Anyway I googled "sabre production api key" and clicked the first result which sent me here: https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/quickstart-guides/get-token which says _prerequisites: You have spoken to a Sabre account manager and/or signed a contract with Sabre. You know which environments you have access to. You know which Sabre APIs you have access to_ Do you have a Sabre account manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different ways to get the apiKey.
If you are a solution development company or if you are a travel agency developing your own solution.
If you are a developer company you should contact Saber directly and sign a development agreement with them.
If you are a travel agency developing an integration then you should contact your account executive and request apiKey.
All this access information via SOAP or REST you can find on their website.

- https://developer.sabre.com/home